# How can we get and verify the transaction receipt?

Tags: ios4, in-app-purchase

In app purchase in which the task is to verify the transaction receipt and also how we can get information in the auto renewal subscription that user is currently subscribed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your application creates a JSON object and posts it to the App Store. The JSON object for an auto-renewable subscription receipt must include a second parameter — the shared secret you created earlier on iTunes Connect:

```
{
    "receipt-data" : "(receipt bytes here)",
    "password"     : "(shared secret bytes here)"
}
```

The response includes a status field that indicates whether the receipt was successfully validated.

```
{
    "status" : 0,
    "receipt" : { (receipt here) },
    "latest_receipt" : "(base-64 encoded receipt here)",
    "latest_receipt_info" : { (latest receipt info here) }
}
```

If the user’s receipt was valid and the subscription is active, the status field holds 0, and the receipt field is populated with the decoded receipt data. If your server receives a non-zero status value, use Table 7-1 to interpret non-zero status codes.